# Correct path to get instagram_manage_messages permission on appreview

Tags: instagram-api

we have a CRM application and our goal is just to monitor Instagram business accounts to receive and manage messages sent to its Direct inbox. We put these messages on queues, one for each different Instagram business account. Thus, some people connect on our CRM application, using our app account credential, to treat those messages, where different user groups can handle different queues.

If we are not mistake, in the past, it was possible request only the instagram_manage_messages permission, but nowadays to get this permission we are obligated to request the instagram_basic too. So, to do that, we are required to implement the “Log In With Facebook” button flow. However, we are asking some doubts to Meta but they only provide us with standard answers that does not help too much.

The main point is which kind of “Log In With Facebook” button flow we need to implement. Most official documentation talks about the regular one, but it does not seems make sense to us, because our users will connect in our application using our application accounts, not their personal Instagram accounts. The only way that could make sense is; of course, use some kind of “Log In With Facebook” button flow to get details about the Instagram business account that will be monitored. However, if I need an app-id to set up the “Log In With Facebook” button, how could I use this authentication to select different business accounts to monitor?

Could anyone help us with details about this flow?

Answer (score 1):

Instagram_basic is mandatory for instagram_manage_messages, and I submitted a form for instagram_manage_messages without using facebook login button in my own crm application. But they didn't accept because of facebook login button. It seemed very strange to me.
If your form has been approved, can you explain how you have progressed in your own crm application. I have been constantly rejected.

Comment: Hello, could you tell me if you were able to complete the Facebook app review?

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to add an fb-login button, though it doesn't make any sense from the first sight.
The problem is that there is no propper instruction to find out what the 'fb-login' button should do.

...
The button is needed for a reviewer to connect their instagram professional account to your fb-application. They ain't gonna use YOUR connected instagram account.

Here is a JS example

1. initialize the FB lib

```html
<script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
          FB.init({
              appId      : "your app's ID",
              cookie     : true,
              xfbml      : true, 
              version    : 'v18.0'
          });
      }; 
    (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

2. add a button somewhere in UI
3. when somesone click the button, you'll need run the following code

```js
window.FB.login(facebookLoginHandler, {
    scope: 'instagram_basic,instagram_manage_messages',
});
```

The 'login' function call will open a popup window.
there you'll need to login to facebook (if you're not logged in)
and link one of your available instagram accounts to your facebook app (by the app ID specified in the init script).

It doesn't make sense from the regular user perspective. But it does for an FB guy who will review you application.